# Is there a way to solve "React is not defined"

Tags: reactjs

[image]I have this plugin that I'm building. Once I run yarn build and try to import the component I want to use from the plugin, I get "React is not defined". How do I solve this error?

Tried importing react in the file, but then once I run yarn build, the line is removed.

Comment: Add some code here where you are getting error.